# Creating a new column which finds the difference in dates based on a conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have the following dataframe:

df=

```
Date     Team1     Team2     
6/1      Boston    New York  
6/13     New York  Chicago   
6/27     Boston    New York  
6/28     Chicago   Boston
```

I would like to create a new column which finds the difference in dates based off the conditional of team1. Ex) when Chicago is Team1 I would like to find the number of days since they last played, regardless of whether or not they were Team1 or Team2 in the previous game.

df=

```
Date     Team1     Team2      Days since Team1 played
6/1      Boston    New York   0
6/13     New York  Chicago    12
6/27     Boston    New York   26
6/28     Chicago   Boston     15
```

Answer (score 3):

Your expected output is close but I would create a multiindex

use `melt` and `diff` then `pivot`

```
# melt to get Teams as one columns
melt = df.melt('Date').sort_values('Date')

# groupby and find the difference
melt['diff'] = melt.groupby('value')['Date'].diff()

# pivot to go back to the original df format
melt.pivot('Date','variable') 

                  value              diff
variable     Team1    Team2     Team1     Team2
      Date              
2018-06-01  Boston   New York    NaT       NaT
2018-06-13  New York Chicago     12 days   NaT
2018-06-27  Boston   New York    26 days   14 days
2018-06-28  Chicago  Boston      15 days   1 days
```

## Update

Here is an update per your comment:

```
# assume this df
    Date         Team1   Team2
0   2018-06-01  Boston    New York
1   2018-06-13  New York  Chicago
2   2018-06-27  Boston    New York
3   2018-06-28  Chicago   Boston
4   2018-06-28  New York  Detroit
```

Code:

```
# melt df (same as above example)
melt = df.melt('Date').sort_values('Date')

# find the difference
melt['diff'] = melt.groupby('value')['Date'].diff()

# use pivot_table not pivot
piv = melt.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'diff'], columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc=lambda x:x)

# reset index and dropna from team 1
piv.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True)
piv = piv[~piv['Team1'].isna()]

# merge your original df and your new one together
pd.merge(df, piv[piv.columns[:-1]], on=['Date','Team1'], how='outer').fillna(0)

         Date   Team1     Team2     diff
0   2018-06-01  Boston    New York  0 days
1   2018-06-13  New York  Chicago   12 days
2   2018-06-27  Boston    New York  26 days
3   2018-06-28  Chicago   Boston    15 days
4   2018-06-28  New York  Detroit   1 days
```

Note that the difference this time is just from the last time Team1 played

Comment: you are correct.. I have corrected the typo in the original post.

Comment: unfortunately I am getting this error when applied to the larger dataframe.    ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape... 
This error is specifically occurring during the third and final step you listed above.

Comment: @RyanG73 that error indicates that the dates are not unique. Does your data contain multiple teams playing on the same date?

Comment: yes, it does. It includes a full season of games when there are night in which there are several games

Comment: @RyanG73 see upadte